# Windows command line: how to "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object"?

Tags: windows, command-line, ntfs

I need the same effect of the checkbox "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object" (directory->Properties->advanced in Windows Explorer) from the command line instead.

This is the GUI (see the highlighted checkbox)

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @optichip for the help! he definitely pointed me in the right direction.

This was the command I was looking for:

```
icacls "C:\MyPath" /reset /T /C
```

Comment: i tried the above command but id doesn't worked

Answer (score 0):

```
icacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player" /grant Administrators:(OI)(CI)M
icacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\*" /grant Administrators:(OI)(CI)M
```

This will set Modify on the folder, and it will also push Administrators group down into the folders underneath it.  You can get more command information doing icacls /? from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but these commands will esplicitely set the permissions on the objects. As I stated, I need to activate inheritance from the parent instead.

Comment: Thought you wanted to push down the highlighted entry... So you are fine with what's there, you just want to enable inheritance? You can do this with icacls [folder] /inheritance:e /t